# How to bind the RUN action to correct NodeJS version in Cloud9?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, cloud9-ide, cloud9

### Background

I have a very sinmple nodejs app that uses the [Object Destructur Operator of ECMA6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

```
"use strict";

function bananas(){
    return {
        type: "fruit",
        color: "yellow"
    };
}

function eat(){
    var {
        type,
        color
    } = bananas();

    return `I eat ${type} colored ${color}`;
}

console.log(eat());
```

### Problem

When I click the run button of index.js (or when you go right-click index.js and then select "Run this file")

I get the following error:

```
Debugger listening on [::]:15454
/home/ubuntu/workspace/server/index.js:16
    var {
        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:441:10)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
```

However, if I type in the bash command line `node index.js` I get the expected output:

> I eat fruit colored yellow

Furthermore, typing `node -v` outputs:

> v7.8.0

### Question

It is my strong believe that the run option is not picking up the correct version of node. 
How can I fix that?

### Notes

To update node I used `nvm install 7`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

My identification of the issue was correct. To fix it one needs to run the following command:

```
nvm alias default 7
```

### Credits

Kudos++ to [Harutyun](https://community.c9.io/users/harutyun) for the answer.